# Is there any Python code to help me replace the years of every date by 2022

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column named `disbursal_date` which is a `datetime`:

```
disbursal_date
2009-01-28
2008-01-03
2008-07-15
```

and so on...

I want to keep the date and month part and replace the years by `2022` for all values.
I tried using `df['disbursal_date'].map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2022))` but this didn't work for me.

Comment: What is the data type of the column -- disbursal ?

Comment: FWIW, if you have any date as Feb. 29th, you'll need to consider how to handle that…

Comment: Don't say 'Python' if you mean 'pandas'. Here you mean 'dataframe'. And we need to know the dtype of the column.  Show us `df.info()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use **apply** not **map** to run a python function on a dataframe columns.
2. We need to make sure that the dtype is datetime of pandas and not object or string.

Below is the sample code I tried and it works fine, it replaces the year to 2022.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['2009-01-28', '2008-01-03', '2008-07-15'],columns=['disbursal_old'])
df['disbursal_old'] = df['disbursal_old'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['disbursal_new'] = df['disbursal_old'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(year=2022))
print(df['disbursal_new'])

0   2022-01-28
1   2022-01-03
2   2022-07-15
Name: disbursal_new, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The below code gives the difference between the years.

```py
df['disbursal_diff_year'] = df['disbursal_new'].dt.year - df['disbursal_old'].dt.year
print(df)

disbursal_old disbursal_new  disbursal_diff_year
0    2009-01-28    2022-01-28                   13
1    2008-01-03    2022-01-03                   14
2    2008-07-15    2022-07-15                   14
```

Comment: I have one more Question
Now that I have disbursal date and this new column with year replaced as 2022, how do I get the year difference between them??

Comment: You mean the year difference from the existing year to the 2022 ?

Comment: Yes...year difference in years not in days

Comment: Updated code, please check and also, please update your question accordingly too.

Comment: Okay I'm new to this so how do I do that?

Comment: Check this out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow and click on the up arrow